# Capistrano multi-server deployment with different parameters

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I would like to deploy a ruby script, `bin/app.rb` to multiple servers

`zone1.myapp.com`, `zone2.myapp.com` & `zone3.myapp.com` using Capistrano v3. Post deployment, it will need to run as a daemon with a param specific to that zone, meaning ...

`zone1` should run `bundle exec ruby bin/app.rb zone1`

`zone2` should run `bundle exec ruby bin/app.rb zone2`

`zone3` should run `bundle exec ruby bin/app.rb zone3`

Is there a way to accomplish this by Capistrano?

Comment: For now it is one script but soon will be an app with few additional classes.